# SailsJS - Helper Module to create links

Tags: node.js, view, sails.js

I want to create helpers ...

like

`function linkTo (value, href, options) {
        .....
}`

But I want this to be global, so I can use to put the links at my views files,

```
<%= linkTo('link','/controller/action') %>
```

Instead of

```
<a href="/controller/action"> Link </a>
```

Should I use a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sails` is built on top of `Express` and `Express` allows you to specify view locals. Just register your functions as middleware in `config/http.js`.

```
/config/http.js

module.exports.http = {

  customMiddleware: function (app) {
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      res.locals.linkTo = function(href, label){
        sails.log("linkTo works!", href, label);
      }
      next();
    });
  }
...
}
```

And use them in your view

```
<%= linkTo('link','/controller/action') %>
```

If you're looking for `linkTo` specifically, theres a library already written for ejs+express that has what you're looking for + many more

https://github.com/mhayashi/express-helpers

Comment: It didnt work, module.exports.express = {
  customMiddleware: function (app) {
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      res.locals.linkTo = function(){...}
      next()
    })
  }
}

Comment: This answer must assume a certain level of express knowledge and have some missing step(s).  Putting that exact file (with a console.log where the ellipses are) in that exact location does not yield the expected result and results in "undefined is not a function".  Also, if I put a syntax error in that file, the server still lifts so the file probably needs to be referenced from somewhere.

Comment: OK, I think this answer is probably just outdated.  If you use config/express instead of api/config/express.js then it works.  Also, you get the warning: "warn: `sails.config.express` is deprecated; use `sails.config.http` instead."  This of course means you can use the /config/http.js file to define your middleware.  I'll update the answer.